# Can not deserialize instance of business.enities.folders.Init out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, angular, jackson, resteasy

I have two entities Folder and Init with a OneToMany relation and when I add a folder, I would like set the init and persist it in DB.. But when I send the forms I got this error in my sclipse console (JAVA)

```
16:24:34,153 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-18) RESTEASY002005: Failed executing POST /folders/saveFolders: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of business.entities.folders.Init out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@2cff0c8; line: 13, column: 16] (through reference chain: business.entities.folders.Folders["initiator"])
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:184)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
```

**Folder.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NOFOLDER")
private String noFolder;
/** Getter + setter **/
```

**Init.java**

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "INIT", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private List<Folders> folders = new ArrayList<Folders>();
/*  Getter  Setter */
```

In My angular I do this for send forms :
**folder.html**

```
<label>No Folder :</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input [(ngModel)]="noFolder" name="noFolder" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input [(ngModel)]="initiator.name" name="name" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input [(ngModel)]="initiator.surname" name="surname" type="text">
</div>

    <button type="button" (click)="saveFolder()">SUBMIT</button>
```

**folder.ts**

```
folder;
initiator;
saveFolder() {
   this.folder.noFolder =  noFolder;
   this.folder.initiator = this.initiator;

     this.folderService.saveFold(this.folder).subscribe(
      data => {
       },
      error => {
     });
}
```

Comment: you got this error from WHAT?

Comment: I got it From JAVA

Comment: tags fixed then ... since this is Resteasy and JSON, not JPA API